# Android - user permission for contacts and location info

Tags: android, location, android-contacts

By default, my android app which I am developing needs the location and the phonebook of the user who installs the app. The counterpart iPhone app pops up with the dialog and ask for user authorization to use both the address and the location info. Whereas, in Android I am not seeing any pop up or restriction in both the simulator as well in the actual physical device in which I am testing.
Can I safely presume that all apps once installed in the android environment will be granted both the location and phone book contact details. Please let me know. If not, is there a way of setting the permission through code or prompt the user for authorization in android?

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android, permissions like these are presented to the user at install time and they must accept them all to continue with the installation so yes.

Comment: Do we need to ask for these permissions? Or once while making it LIVE in google play we need to indicate it? Please let me know.

Comment: You add the permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml`
You can see a full list of them here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: You want:
READ_CONTACTS
and
ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION (geo-ip) or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION (GPS)

Comment: And you declare them in your manifest like this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#permissions

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html):

```
The permissions required by an application are declared statically in that application, so they can be known up-front at install time and will not change after that.
```

Comment: Thanks for that Vazeer. If the user does not agree (if the user do not want his contacts to be exposed) and clicks on the Cancel button, do I need to include any code in my app which needs to get executed for the cancel button click event. Please let me know